# Setting anonymous cipher on GCDAsyncSocket

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ssl, encryption, gcdasyncsocket

Is there any way to enable anonymous ciphers in the GCDAsyncSocket library? So as to connect to a weakly protected server via TLS/SSL.

Comment: Try and include tags with a minimum amount of followers and at least some tags that indicate the runtime environment (specifying objective-c will also provide auto syntax highlighting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the elementary question. Just read the docs again and worked it out. It is like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *settings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSArray* ciphers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA], nil];

[settings setObject:ciphers forKey:GCDAsyncSocketSSLCipherSuites];

[socket startTLS:settings];
```

Yep, just set an NSArray containing all the necessary cipher suites as a value for key `GCDAsyncSocketSSLCipherSuites`.

Comment: Hi pb593 and welcome. Thanks for reporting back and providing the answer + code.